# RESTEasy's SpringContextLoaderListener not scanning @Path

Tags: java, spring, resteasy, autowired

I'm trying to implements RESTEasy + Spring, but @Autowire not working. I found some reference that I need to use org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener and disable resteasy auto scan. I've tried, but now my web service is not recognize. What do I do wrong? Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>APF Web Service</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- REST configuration -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- RESTEasy <-> Spring connector (RESTEasy can access Spring beans) -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/json/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/json</param-value>
</context-param>

<!--<context-param>-->
    <!--<param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>-->
    <!--<param-value>ApplicationSvc</param-value>-->
<!--</context-param>-->

<!-- End of REST configuration -->

</web-app>
```

Here is my web service

```
@Service
@Path("/json")
public class ApplicationSupportSvc {

    @Autowired
    private MobileSurveyApkRepo mobileSurveyApkRepo;

    @GET
    @Path("/latest")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional
    public ApkResponse getLatestApk() {

        return mobileSurveyApkRepo.getLatestApk();
    }

}
```

And here is my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="some.package" />
<context:annotation-config />
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true"></aop:config>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/SomeConn" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[

            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
            hibernate.default_schema=FIN
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.keywords=auto-quote
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            javax.persistence.validation.mode=none

            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>some.package</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jbpm.execution.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:jbpm.history.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:jbpm.task.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:jbpm.repository.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:jbpm.identity.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj" />

<!-- End of Hibernate session factory -->

<!-- jBPM4 Bean Definitions -->
<bean id="springHelper" class="org.jbpm.pvm.internal.processengine.SpringHelper">
    <property name="jbpmCfg">
        <value>jbpm.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="processEngine" factory-bean="springHelper"
      factory-method="createProcessEngine" />

<bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine"
      factory-method="getRepositoryService" />

<bean id="executionService" factory-bean="processEngine"
      factory-method="getExecutionService" />

<bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine"
      factory-method="getTaskService" />

<bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine"
      factory-method="getHistoryService" />

<bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine"
      factory-method="getManagementService" />

<!-- End of jBPM4 Bean Definitions -->

</beans>
```

I'm using RESTEasy 3.0.6 and Spring 4.0.3, with JBOSS EAP 6.2

Comment: What is the name of the Spring configuration file? Are you using XML or Java Config?

Comment: Hi geoand, I use XML configuration, applicationContext.xml

Comment: Try removing the `resteasy.scan` context-param, and also add `    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/json</param-value>
    </context-param>` to web.xml. A similar setup has worked for me using Tomcat

Comment: I've tried that with still no result ;(. Is it cause by JBOSS?

Comment: I have no idea if the problem is JBOSS or not, since I have never worked with it. But as I mentioned a similar setup has worked for me with Tomcat, and is also shown in blog posts like this one http://blog.comsysto.com/2012/08/02/resteasy-integration-with-spring-tutorial-part-1-introduction/

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug with RESTEasy and Spring 4: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1012

Create your own `ContextLoaderListener` implementation as per the issue's description.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed in Resteasy 3.0.9.Final: 
https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-spring/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/spring/SpringContextLoaderListener.java

Now you can use the following:

1. pom.xml

> ```
> ...
> <properties>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
>     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
>     <org.springframework-version>4.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
>     <spring-security-config-version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring-security-config-version>
>     <servlet-version>3.1.0</servlet-version>
>     <org.jboss.resteasy-version>3.0.9.Final</org.jboss.resteasy-version>
>     <javax.inject-version>1</javax.inject-version>
> </properties>
> <dependencies>
>     <!-- Spring -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>         <type>jar</type>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- Servlet -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
>         <version>${servlet-version}</version>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- JSR 330: Dependency Injection for Java -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
>         <version>${javax.inject-version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- JAX-RS -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
>         <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.jboss.resteasy-version}</version>
>     </dependency>       
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
>         <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.jboss.resteasy-version}</version>
>         <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>        
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
>         <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.jboss.resteasy-version}</version>
>         <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
>         <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.jboss.resteasy-version}</version>
>         <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
>         <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.jboss.resteasy-version}</version>
>         <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> ```

2. web.xml

> ```
> <listener>
>     <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
> </listener>
> <listener>
>     <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
> </listener>
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
>     <param-value>/rest</param-value>
> </context-param>
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>rest-servlet</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
> </servlet>
> <!-- NEVER map servlet to root context "/*" ! -->
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>rest-servlet</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

3. Rest class

> ```
> // JSR 330: Dependency Injection for Java
> @Named
> @Path("api/v1")
> @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
> @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
> ```

```
 public class SomeResource {

    @Inject
    @Named("someService")
    private SomeServiceInterface someService;

    @Inject
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @GET
    @Path("{msg}")
    public Response ehlo(@PathParam("msg") String msg) {
        return Response.ok().entity(msg).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Working fine with Resteasy 3.0.9

Answer (score 0):

You also need a spring configuration file.
RESTEasy expects a applicationContext.xml file in your WEB-INF directory.

This file should contain something similar to:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="
    my.package"/>
```

Comment: Hi Danix :), I already add component-scan and annotation-config to my application context, as beans the ApplicationSupportSvc works just fine. The problem is, because I remove resteasy automatic scan, I can't access my web service (http://localhost:8080/json/latest), the server returns 404. I read that SpringContextLoaderListener will automatically scans for @Path (I assume it works like resteasy autoscan), but it didn't work for me.

Comment: RESTEasy doesn't expect it, Spring expects it. the RESTEasy dosc never mention that xml file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can solve this 
1)use   where some.package is where MobileSurveyApkRepo is declared.
or 
2)get Webapplciationcontext and get the bean 
why you are autowiring it and again why you are doing this
MobileSurveyApkRepo mobileSurveyApkRepo = ctx.getBean("mobileSurveyApkRepoImpl", MobileSurveyApkRepo.class);

Comment: Hi geddamsatish, sorry I forgot to remobe the ctx.getBean :). I got it works using ServletContext as parameter (your second suggestion). I just wonder, seems like everyone else can use @Autowire following the common guide (use SpringContextLoaderListener and remove resteasy autoscan), but I can't. I want to know what I do wrong.

Comment: Share your spring.xml people can help you.Its all about configuration.

Comment: Ok, I've share my spring application context

Comment: you shared pom.xml not application context

Comment: Aw, sorry my bad. Fixed it.

Comment: No, still not working. I mean I fixed the pom.xml reference at my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you had to take out the resteasy auto-scan, you probably need to list your rest services like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mypackage.MyRESTService</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.Pleas try this.

Step1: Instead of using the SpringContextLoaderListener try the default ContextLoaderListener from spring framework in web.xml

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And Add the resteasy.scan in web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Step2: In POM file add the below 2 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
<version>3.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Step3: And in applicationContext.xml add the below bean definition above component-scan

```
<bean class="org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessorServletAware"/>
```

Hope this helps.